# MVVM Model for a collection of models?

Tags: mvvm

As I'm learning the MVVM pattern, I've hit a question. I'm building a sample notes application. In this application you can see a list of notes with NotesView. The DataContext of NotesView is NotesModelView.

My question is should NotesModelView contain a collection of NoteModel or NoteModelView (which contains a NoteModel)?

Answer (score 2):

I always wrap my models in view models. This way any changes made by the user are only applied to the view models and not to the underlying models until the user wants to commit those changes (via e.g. a Save button) and if the user doesn't want to commit, you can just throw away the view model and start from scratch without your model being changed. This is especially important when dealing with database entities/objects as changes made directly to an entity can be painful to rollback (at least if you're using Entity Framework)

There are certain cases when a "commit" is implicit and the above doesn't apply, but I still think it's good practice to use view models as it also allows you to unit test your business logic. The main motivation behind MVVM is maintainability and having good unit tests in place is one way of achieving that.

Answer (score 1):

I tend to favor wrapping all the model classes into viewmodels so my general answer would be to have a collection of `NoteViewModel` that wraps a `NoteModel`.

But I'm also a fan of the [DRY principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself), so in those cases where the ViewModel doesn't add any benefits at all (e.g. I don't need to re-format the data and I don't need change notification and I don't mind exposing the raw model to the view) I sometimes break this rule.

Since you are trying to learn MVVM my suggestion for this particular case is to **go with a collection of viewmodels**. This will give you a better understanding of MVVM and help you make these distinctions later when your faced with this question in a future app.

Comment: Thanks for the advice - I'm still climbing that steep learning curve, so I want to make sure I understand the pattern properly before I start deviating from it.

Comment: No problem.. And feel free to vote up all the answers you find helpful ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, your naming is slightly confusing, I would pick on a cleaner naming standard!  It's usual for people to postfix views with 'View', and view models with 'ViewModel'.

So in your case, have a NotesView whose DataContext is a NotesViewModel.  On your NotesViewModel, you should have a collection of Notes (or NotesModel if you wish to call it that).  Your NotesViewModel shouldn't have a collection of NotesViewModel, because this is unnecessary, as you probably only want to display the Note data in your NotesView.

Comment: Sorry for the confusing naming, and rest asssured it's not the naming style I use in the application. I just thought it would be easier to understand if I postfixed the models with 'Model' too.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, you should have Note - as a Model and you should define ObservableCollection of Note type the list which will represent the list of your models.
This list will be in your ViewModel and you can bind it to any View in your project